# UICollectionView vertical scrolling automatically every 3 seconds

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app which need to make a scroll in a collection view automatically

```
class resultsViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSource , UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var numberCount = 3
    var scrollIndex = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

          let flow = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)
        let width = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width - 6
        flow.itemSize = CGSizeMake(width/3, width/3)
        flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 3
        flow.minimumLineSpacing = 3
        flow.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0,10,0);





        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.doAfterThreeSecods()
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("imageSearch", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! imagesCollectionViewCell
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberCount
    }

    func doAfterThreeSecods()
    {

        numberCount += 3
        collectionView.reloadData()

        let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(3 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

            self.doAfterThreeSecods()
        }
    }

}
```

that's append 3 cells every three seconds

i just need to make scroll the next row when i append the three cells

```
  self.collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(index: self.scrollIndex), atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)
```

but the app crash and the error was :

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path:  {length = 1, path = 6}'**

anyone can help

Comment: doAfterThreeSecods is calling it's self after every 3sec . and as collectionView.reloadData() is called here so it is also call after every 3secs.

Comment: scrollIndex not incremented in doAfterThreeSecond is calling

Comment: scroll before the cell append or the cell number calculated wrong, its 0->5 for 6 cell

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this in a wrong way.That's why it throws invalid index path errors. For example take that you have 3 collection view to show. Let's name it as image01,image02,image03. So your array should be like [image03,image01,image02,image03,image01]. You should append last element to first and first element to last. The answer is quite broad to describe. Hence here is article which describe this theroy.

```
 Article :-
```

> https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2013/07/building-a-circular-gallery-with-a-uicollectionview/